# Add the fxml file in the exported jar file

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to export a jar file from a javafx project i have created in the ideallij. I did the properties for the artifacts, by adding all my jar libraries in the output. Then, I build the artifact and the jar file is created. However, when i am trying to run the jar from the terminal with `java - jar name.jar` I am receiving the following error:

> Exception in Application start method, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

The error points in the fxml file. How can I add the fxml file in the compressed jar file?

FXML loading:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(EchoClient.class.getResource("name.fxml"));
    Parent p = fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(p);
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.setTitle("FX Echo Client");
    primaryStage.setWidth( 320 );
    primaryStage.setHeight(568);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The error is located in `Parent p = fxmlLoader.load();`.The error am receiving is the following:

[image]

**EDIT:** After a bit of research I came to the conclusion that my problem is ideantical with the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132302/invocationtargetexception-when-running-a-javafx-program). Thus I removed the  remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the **FXML file** and the jar was normally called without the functionality of the application though. How cam I add the controller functionality back to the code?

My fxml file is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="services.EchoClientController">
    <children>
        <VBox spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES">
            <children>
                <Label text="Host" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfHost" text="localhost" />
                <Label text="Port" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfPort" text="10000" />
                <HBox spacing="4.0">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnConnect" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connect" text="Connect" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnDisconnect" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#disconnect" text="Disconnect" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </VBox>
        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
        <VBox spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <Label text="Message To Send" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfSend" />
                <Button fx:id="btnSend" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#send" text="Send" />
                <Label text="Message Received" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfReceive" editable="false" />
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </VBox>
        <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
        <VBox VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
            <children>
                <HBox fx:id="hboxStatus" spacing="10.0">
                    <children>
                        <ProgressBar fx:id="piStatus" prefWidth="150.0" progress="0.0" />
                        <Label fx:id="lblStatus" text="Label" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: At least show us how you load the fxml file through code.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Well you still need to show us your project setup where your files are located , you packages etc.

Comment: *"The error points in the fxml file."* If this is true there is an issue with the fxml file and not with adding it to the jar...

Comment: The code is working, i am loading properly the fxml file and the whole scene is depicted.

Comment: If the fxml is loaded through IDE and breaks when you export the project that has to do with only two cases ( at least in my opinion ). 
1. you are not loading the fxml correctly which means you don't have specify the full path.
2. The fxml loads an image or some files and it breaks there for the same reason as the (1)

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question, and the corresponding code that it points to.

Comment: It would be helpful to know a little about your project, specifically where the fxml is located and what build system (maven etc.) you use to build the jar.

Comment: The fxml file is located in the services folder. And i am building the jar file using the idelij artifacts. Am not familiar with maven.

Comment: Running the program from idellij is not an issue, everything is working fine. However, when I am building the jar I am receiving from the terminal the issue for loading the fxml.

Answer (score 3):

I usually get this error when there is a typo in the .fxml file. I think the file itself flows to the .jar file, there is just something in there which cannot be resolved. You can prove that by deleting most of the fxml content temporary (make sure there will be no reference from the Java code to any missing GUI element) to see if the error disappears.

Comment: Is there a chance that has to do with the path of the fxml file?

Comment: If the stage has the correct link to the FXML, then I don't think so. Try out my suggested solution to exclude the possibility of this.

Answer (score 2):

The error could only originate from `services.EchoClientController`, missing:

```
@FXML
private void connect() {
}

@FXML
private void disconnect() {
}

@FXML
private void send() {
}
```

As it cannot be that simple, look at the constructor and consider using:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // Maybe constructor code here.
}
```

Instead of

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = 
        new FXMLLoader(EchoClient.class.getResource("name.fxml"));
Parent p = fxmlLoader.load();
```

I did (what should not make a difference)

```
Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(EchoClient.class.getResource("name.fxml"));
```