# Java FX path for .fxml files doesn´t work when exporting to JAR

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX project which runs this way:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
```

My folder scheme is like this:

[image]

It works great in Eclipse but when I export it into a Runnable JAR and execute it from the console, it does:

[image]

I put in the jar folder my `Login.fxml` different ways:

- In the same folder
- In a folder called `resources`
- Inside `application` inside `resources`

But none of this is working. Where I am supposed to place my `Login.fxml` file?

**I would appreciate some help here. Thank you.**

Comment: Make sure your FXML file path is right. Clean build and export the jar again.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Alredy did it.

Comment: can you find fxml files inside the jar archive?

Comment: What's the error you're getting in terminal?

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal I just uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133196/5818995

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal I have loader.setController(this); (In the controller class), so I guess I'm doing the same, i don't use the fx: controller attribute in the Login.fxml

Comment: What result does the `System.out.println` give?

Comment: @M.leRutte file:/C:/Users/Clopma/Desktop/Repos/PFG/ProyectoFinal/target/classes/application/Login.fxml Check my update!

Comment: Note that the update now gives an error on image loading,  not on the FXML.

Comment: @M.leRutte Yes, I alredy answered my own question, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

My `Login.fxml` class was inside the `application` package.
So i created a application folder inside the folder in wich the jar file is:

[image]

And inside application folder I peasted the `Login.fxml` file.

I also created `res` and `src` for other resources.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that non-java files have landed within `src` directory inside the jar, so I simply added `src/` before fxml file path. Not the best solution but it allows to generate working runnable jar file.