# Apache Netbeans 20 keeps giving "InvocationTargetException" even in new Ant JavaFX FXML projects

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I've added the library for JavaFX using https://openjfx.io/ and I've added the Java Platform from [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk-fx#zulu), which is the JavaJDK FX. I also have Scenebuilder. When creating a new project, I used Java with Ant > JavaFX FXML Application.

Please note that this is from a fresh reinstall, and no modifications except removing the comments:

Comeonwork.java:

```
package comeonwork;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Comeonwork extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

FXMLDocument.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="comeonwork.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
package comeonwork;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
    
}
```

When I try to run Comeonwork.java, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3369)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)
    at comeonwork.Comeonwork.start(Comeonwork.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application comeonwork.Comeonwork
C:\Users\Aun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\comeonwork\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1367: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Aun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\comeonwork\nbproject\build-impl.xml:962: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I'm not getting any error from the syntax, since Netbeans seems to be recognizing it all, but I can't run the project.

I've looked through several websites, stackoverflow questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132302/invocationtargetexception-when-running-a-javafx-program)) and those don't answer my question. I tried a fresh reinstall (uninstalling netbeans and trying again, reinstalling the platforms and libraries, making sure the project's library is JavaFX jdk) but nothing is working. Clean and build asks me for Available classes but the list is blank.

Edit: here's the thing. It usually doesn't work, but sometimes it does, so I have no idea why it's happening. And if it somehow clean and build without asking for available classes, there's an error called "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript"

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) Follow the troubleshooting steps in the answer.  FYI, it would appear your JavaFX installation is functioning fine because you are running a JavaFX app, it is just that your resource lookup for the FXML file appears wrong.

Comment: Try running the simple [hello world app](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java) from openjfx (that has no FXML so it is simpler than the code you are trying to run, and it eliminates FXML processing as a source of potential issues you may have).  openjfx also has getting started instructions for [JavaFX and NetBeans](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans) if you need them.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the hello world app and it works fine. The clean and build even detected the java class. I reverted back to the original and clean and build it (no available classes prompt, for some reason) and it's running. But I tried creating a new project and the problem is still there. The path for the FXML file is correct though, since the java file is in the same foldere as the FXML file

Comment: The lookup for the FXML is not correct. If it were, you wouldn't receive a NullPointerException with a Location is required error.  It doesn't matter where the FXML file is relative to a `.java` file.  A `.java` file is a source file, it doesn't even exist at runtime.  It only matters where the FXML file is located relative to the class file you are performing the resource lookup from via `getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml")`.  In your case, that would be wherever `Comeonwork.class` is located, because that is the class you are making the resource lookup call from.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. I tried `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Comeonwork.class.getResource("FXMLDocument.FXML"));` since, if I'm understanding it correctly, should get FXMLDocument but it's not working right now

Comment: Well, following the troubleshooting in the duplicate, where is the class file you are executing located?  Is it in a jar or on the file system in the build output somewhere?  And next to that **.class** file, in the jar file or on the file system, is your FXML document there?  If not, you have an issue with how you have defined your build setup.

Comment: I recommend using a build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle) in conjunction with your IDE's integration with your chosen build tool.  openjfx documentation explains how to do that for your IDE.  Follow the [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611206/2423906

Answer (score 2):

Your FXML file appears to be named `FXMLDocument.java`. Changing the name to match the name specified in the FXML file's `fx:controller` attribute allows the program to run correctly.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611827/230513), a *Java with Ant > Java Application* project is convenient as a scratch project, but it profoundly limits deployment opportunities. Going forward, consider adopting [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611206/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info); a complete example may be found [here](https://github.com/trashgod/modular).