# Error when creating EXE JAVA application in NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

My project works will but I want to create EXE of my Java program and when I select Pajage as EXE installer I get this error message "**Unable to create javax script engine for javascrip**t"
+
I downgraded the java from 20.0 JDK to 14.2 and now I get the new error message "**typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found**",
is there any way to fix this or a new way to do it ??
and thanks a lot.

+
I followed this video {
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS5PdJ5ghY4&ab_channel=CodingwithSudhir](https://stackoverflow.com)
}

Comment: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941665/230513), even a recent a NetBeans `ant` project may limit deployment flexibility.

Comment: The link leads to a `Swing` tutorial.

Comment: my project works will, but I cant create an EXE app version of it.

Comment: See the section on [_Packaging_](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for other deployment strategies.

Comment: thanks a lot, i used lunch4j and its creates the exe app, but then I app note works well as it should save data in SQLite DB I think the exe version does not create the database